# Why Abs[Infinity] is an element of the real numbers

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, simplifying-expressions

```
Element[Abs[Infinity], Complexes]
```

returns False, that's right.

But

```
Limit[Element[Abs[x], Reals], x -> Infinity]
ForAll[{x}, x == Infinity, Element[Abs[x], Reals]]
```

returns True,

```
FullSimplify[expr = Sqrt[1/x^2], Element[x, Reals]]
Exists[{x}, x == 0, Element[%, Reals]] // FullSimplify
Exists[{x}, x == 0, Element[expr, Reals]] // FullSimplify
```

it seems unreasonable.

Comment: However, `Element[Abs[Infinity], Reals]` return `False`.

Comment: @murray: Yes, but sometimes Abs[Infinty] with some logical functions will contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking `ForAll` with vacuous conditions. Compare:

```
ForAll[{x}, x == x + 1, Element[Abs[x], Reals]]
(* output: True *)
```

I think that is really all that's going on here. There is no `x` in the `ForAll` for which `x==Infinity` actually returns true, so it spits out true because the "all" in "for all" is the empty set. It's vacuous.

Likewise in the limit, you have a constant sequence `True`. What is the limit of that? Nobody said the map from set membership to truth values was continuous. Compare:

```
Limit[x < Infinity, x -> Infinity]
(* output: True *)
```

I don't see anything fishy going on here, but this is at least somewhat curious a topic. Have I overlooked something, or is it really just business as usual as I seem to say?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how to interpret `Exists[x,x==0,Element[Abs[1/x],Reals]]//FullSimplify` and `Exists[x, x == 0, Element[Sqrt[1/x^2], Reals]] // FullSimplify`

Comment: `Abs[1/0]` gives you `Infinity` while `Sqrt[1/0]` gives `ComplexInfinity`. The absolute value function returns a real, while square roots of this sort will return complex-valued numbers unless the input is a positive real. (This isn't a Mathematica issue, that's just how square roots work.)

Comment: All right. Focus on `Exists` `x==0` return `True`, it isn't vacuous.

Comment: What do you mean "focus on Exists"? I'm not really sure I understand that. The `Exists` command has three inputs, `Exists[x,cond,expr]`, where `cond` is a condition on `x` and `expr` is the expression you are quantifying. Note that `Exists[x,cond,expr]` is equivalent to `Exists[x,cond&&expr]`. When `Exists` looks at `Abs[1/x]` it determines that this is real. See also: `Reduce[ForAll[x, Element[Abs[1/x], Reals]]]` . Because of that, it has reduced `x==0&&Element[Abs[1/x],Reals]` to `x==0&&True`, for which `x` does exist. This simplification will not occur with the `Sqrt` construction.

Comment: I will also point out that using `x==0` within an `Exists` command doesn't make sense. I'm sure you know that, but you can't expect perfect results when threading division by zero and existential quantifiers together.